# How to display specific user information in a separate page using flask and flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I made only one table in my application. I want to display some information on the page admin.html and
**specific user information** on info.html page. How should I give the query to show the particular user information on which client has clicked on the admin page. I want to display other attributes of my database like email, phone number, college name only on the info.html page. Here are my files:

database

```
class database(db.Model):
    id=db.Column('user_id',db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    text=db.Column(db.String(1000))
    personality_score=db.Column(db.Integer)
    skills_score=db.Column(db.Integer)
    experience_score=db.Column(db.Integer)
    total_score=db.Column(db.Integer)
    college=db.Column(db.String(100))
    email=db.Column(db.String(100))
    phone_number=db.Column(db.String(100))
```

app.py

```
@app.route('/admin')
def admin():
    return render_template('admin.html',database=database.query.order_by(database.total_score.desc()).all())

@app.route('/info')
def info():
    return render_template('info.html')
```

admin.html

```
<table class="css-serial">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th>Rank</th>
               <th>ID</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Profile Summary</th>
               <th>Personality Score</th>
               <th>Skills Score</th>
               <th>Experience Score</th>
               <th>Total Score</th>
            </tr><tr>
               {% for data in database %}
                  <td></td>
                  <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                  <td><a href=info>{{ data.name }}</a></td>
                  <td>{{ data.text }}</td>
                  <td>{{ data.personality_score }}</td>
                  <td>{{data.skills_score}}</td>
                  <td>{{data.experience_score}}</td>
                  <td>{{data.total_score}}</td>
               </tr></tbody>
               {% endfor %}
      </table>
```

I have not written anything in the info.html file because I was not able to figure out how to fetch 'id' or data to display on that page.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you want to move to ```info.html``` page if the user clicks on the anchor tag on the ```{{ data.name }}``` is it ?

Comment: Yes I wanted to do that. I added "<td><a href=info/{{data.id}}>{{ data.name }}</a></td>" in admin.html file. This way i was able to show specific user information through info.html file. I think my question was not completely clear. Thanks for the answer. It improved my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that I understood your question correctly, here's what you wish to do:

1. You want to click on the anchor tag on the `{{data.name}}` and the person should first be redirected to the '/info' route.
2. On that route, the information associated with the person whose name was clicked is to be showed.

(1) is re-routing concept in flask. For which we use `url_for` method.

(2) is a basic WHERE query in sqlAlchemy ORM for which we can use the `filter_by` filter and `first()` collector.

Your route '/info' should take a parameter, user id,  which we will use to filter the user information. Preferably, the info route can be changed as follows:

```
@app.route('/info/<id>')
def info(id):
    user_info = database.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    return render_template('info.html', information=user_info)
```

Change your admin.html as follows:

```
<table class="css-serial">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Profile Summary</th>
      <th>Personality Score</th>
      <th>Skills Score</th>
      <th>Experience Score</th>
      <th>Total Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      {% for data in database %}
      <td></td>
      <td>{{data.id}}</td>
      <td>
        <a href="{{url_for('app.info', id=data.id)}}">{{ data.name }}</a>
      </td>
      <td>{{ data.text }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.personality_score }}</td>
      <td>{{data.skills_score}}</td>
      <td>{{data.experience_score}}</td>
      <td>{{data.total_score}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

If you pay attention, in the method that's executed in the './info' route, we have added a parameter which will be used to filter information from the database.

`filter_by` basically creates the `WHERE` clause in any SQL based database and the `first()` is a collector of the information, which will basically give the information corresponding to the first row, that is satisfying the filter.

Since two people can have the same name, we pass the `{{data.id}}` in the filter.

Using the `information` parameter passed in the `render_template()` of '/info' route you can make the info.html page.

So this should work. I have answered the question based on my understanding of the question.

Your question was unclear.

Let me know if you don't understand something or if I have misunderstood something.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It worked. @keshav

Answer (score 1):

First, retrieve all the data in the `database` table in, say, the `info()` view function:

```py
@app.route('/info')
def info():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    user_info = database.query.order_by(
        database.timestamp.desc()).paginate(
            page, app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'], False
        )
    next_url = url_for('info',
                       page=user_info.next_num) \
        if user_info.has_next else None
    prev_url = url_for('info',
                       page=user_info.prev_num) \
        if user_info.has_prev else None
    return render_template('info.html',
                           title='User Information',
                           next_url=next_url,
                           prev_url=prev_url,
                           user_info=user_info.items
                           )
```

In my example, I am querying the `database` in the order of the time a user was recorded in the `database`. For now you do not have that field, but I just wanted to point that out in case you want to use it. That would mean you add a new column `timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)` to `database`.

Additionally, I have added pagination such that in the event your database has so many entries, you can choose to show a certain amount of data in per page, with the option to move to page 2, 3 ... Read more [from the documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/).

With data now in `user_info`, you can use a `for` loop to display all user information.

```html
<table class="css-serial">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th>Rank</th>
               <th>ID</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Profile Summary</th>
               <th>Personality Score</th>
               <th>Skills Score</th>
               <th>Experience Score</th>
               <th>Total Score</th>
            </tr>
            {% for data in user_info %}
               <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                  <td><a href=info>{{ data.name }}</a></td>
                  <td>{{ data.text }}</td>
                  <td>{{ data.personality_score }}</td>
                  <td>{{data.skills_score}}</td>
                  <td>{{data.experience_score}}</td>
                  <td>{{data.total_score}}</td>
            </tr>
           {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
</table>
```